# Facebook hide scrollbar partially in streams

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, facebook-likebox

I have a problem with the plugin like-box facebook, if you look at the fiddle scroll disappears when lowering, and modified the data-height but still no result, me and fixed with the inspector that this is set to either javascript by facebook at a height of 300px

```
 <div class="phm pluginLikeboxStream" style="height: 300px">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Norant/mg5P7/5/

I appreciate your help

Comment: Yes I could do it with javascript responsive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the minimum height looks like it should be `388px`, even when playing with the [Facebook like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/) it breaks when the height is smaller than `388px`. This doesn't seem to be a problem with anything you did, it seems to be something Facebook did. It seems like this is something they should fix since people might want the box to be smaller than their minimum.